# Why (int)double.NaN and (int)double.PositiveInfinity are 0?

Tags: c#

in **C#**, if you `0/0` you get an exception.

But if you `0.0/0` or `0.0/0.0` you get `double.NaN` and `double.Infinity`, respectively.

but if you cast these results to `int`, you get 0.

```
> (int)double.PositiveInfinity
0
> (int)double.NaN
0
```

Why is this the case? Isn't the runtime supposed to give casting error because infinity is clearly not a zero?

Comment: What tool are you using? In a normal app, `NaN == -2147483648`, or an exception when using `checked {}`

Comment: In my own small app, (int)Double.NaN is -1 on a x64 machine and 0 on an Arm. This caused all sorts of very odd problems!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It depends on what kind of context you're in. If you use a `checked` context, you'll get an exception. The relevant section of the spec is section 6.2.1:

> For a conversion from float or double to an integral type, the processing depends on the overflow checking context (§7.6.12) in which the conversion takes place:
>
> - In a checked context, the conversion proceeds as follows:
>
>   - If the value of the operand is NaN or infinite, a System.OverflowException is thrown.
>   - Otherwise, the source operand is rounded towards zero to the nearest integral value. If this integral value is within the range of the destination type then this value is the result of the conversion.
>   - Otherwise, a System.OverflowException is thrown.
> - In an unchecked context, the conversion always succeeds, and proceeds as follows.
>
>   - If the value of the operand is NaN or infinite, the result of the conversion is an unspecified value of the destination type.
>   - Otherwise, the source operand is rounded towards zero to the nearest integral value. If this integral value is within the range of the destination type then this value is the result of the conversion.
>   - Otherwise, the result of the conversion is an unspecified value of the destination type.

So in an unchecked context, the answer *isn't* necessarily 0 - it's an unspecified `int` value. In fact, in my testing, it comes up as `int.MinValue` rather than 0 in an unchecked context.

But fundamentally, if you want to do checking, use a checked context (at least for that expression).

Comment: @AppDeveloper: I'm sitting in a room with a bunch of the engineers in the C# team, so definitely not feeling that way at the moment :)

Comment: everyone dont have the same pleasure :D!

Comment: well seriously, how u keep all these stuff in memory?

Comment: @AppDeveloper: Who says I have it in memory? I opened up the C# spec and searched for "numeric conversion".

Comment: sorry if i sound stupid, is the c# spec available for public reading?

Comment: @AppDeveloper Yes, just ask Google for it.  (That's kinda the point of the spec; to be a public document that customers can verify against.)

Comment: @AppDeveloper: It's also installed as part of Visual Studio, e.g. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC#\Specifications

Comment: Jon Skeet: Sitting in a room with _engineers in the C# team_, yet bouncing around SO answering questions instead.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: As well, not instead :)

Comment: Jon Skeet: Sitting in a room with _engineers in the C# team_ kicking back and having fun on SO with them.

Answer (score 0):

This is mainly due to the fact that double.NAN and double.PositiveInfity ( or double.Negative for the matter) are not numbers but rather values to identify a concept.

A method or operator returns NaN when the result of an operation is **undefined**. For example, the result of dividing zero by zero is NaN, as the following example shows.

try this to illustrate that concept.

```
if ((0 / zero) == Double.NaN) 
     Console.WriteLine("0 / 0 can be tested with Double.NaN.");
  else 
     Console.WriteLine("0 / 0 cannot be tested with Double.NaN; use Double.IsNan() instead.");
```